# How do I redirect to any kind of a URI (data, blob, http etc.) in Flask?

Tags: python, flask, redirect, http-redirect

I need to redirect to a URI that can be not just HTTP(S) using Flask. It can be a data uri, a blob uri, an ftp uri, etc. How do I?

I tried using `Flask.redirect()` but that did not work on data URIs, nor did it work on URIs with no protocol specified (like google.com).
MRE:

```
from flask import Flask, redirect
app = Flask(__name__)
@app.route("/")
def redir_test(): return redirect("google.com")
# redirects to /google.com, shold redirect to http://google.com
```

I tried using `<meta HTTP-EQUIV="REFRESH" content="0; url=URL">` to redirect. That worked well with data URIs, but did not work with protocolless URIs (google.com redirected to /google.com).
MRE:

```
from flask import Flask
app = Flask(__name__)
@app.route("/")
def redir_test(): return '<meta HTTP-EQUIV="REFRESH" content="0; url=google.com">'
# redirects to /google.com, shold redirect to http://google.com
```

Comment: Note that your flask app doesn’t do things that your browser can do like automatically resolving the right protocol for a domain, automatically changing http to https upon encountering [HSTS](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/Strict-Transport-Security#:~:text=The%20HTTP%20Strict%2DTransport%2DSecurity,automatically%20be%20converted%20to%20HTTPS.). So if you insist on programmatic redirects, you ought to handle edge cases yourself.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```py
def redir_test(): 
    return redirect("google.com") # redirects to /google.com, should redirect to https://google.com
```

### No

Python Flask cannot do that. These functionalities are a bit complicated and require some effort from the developers end to achieve. Some of the functionalities you mentioned include [HSTS](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/Strict-Transport-Security#:%7E:text=The%20HTTP%20Strict%2DTransport%2DSecurity,automatically%20be%20converted%20to%20HTTPS.), [PAC](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Proxy_auto-config#context) e.t.c

**Why does the browser have these?**
Because it is built into the browser.

Note: while [HSTS is standardized](https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/rfc6797), automatically converting a [File Transfer Protocol](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/File_Transfer_Protocol) to [Hyper Text Transfer Protocol](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/HTTP) is not standardized.

Comment: Is there some library that can do all that, then? Maybe a way to input a url into a browser and then get it back?

Comment: I’m sorry but I can’t really think of any suggestions to make. I haven’t used any so I can’t give you a proper opinion. This will be difficult in all honesty. Trying to achieve it on your own isn’t advisable either because you might run into bugs (no, you will definitely run into bugs). Rather use what is within your reach at the moment and use it the right way. It will probably suffice for 90% of the cases.